# Por que o Java não soma os números em expressão?

Tags: java, operadores, tipagem

```
public class Teste {      
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 2;
    System.out.print(x + y + z);
  }      
}
```

Isto retorna: 3

```
public class Teste {      
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 2;
    System.out.print(x + " " + y + z);
  }      
}
```

Isto retorno: 0 12, por que? Não tinha que ser: 0 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não, são tipos diferentes, a operação precisa ser normalizada para um tipo só, e tem que ser um que todos funcionem bem.

A *string* não funciona bem com números, que número ela seria para somar?

Então todos os operandos são consideramos como *string* e só há uma concatenação e não um uma soma.

Todos os tipos do Java podem ser convertidos para *string*, embora nem sempre de forma adequada. Só algumas *strings* podem ser convertidas em número e não é função do compilador verificar isto, até porque em grande parte das vezes nem saberá que valor é.

Isto se dá por causa da associatividade e precedência de operadores (nesse caso a precedência não importa porque é o mesmo operador em todas sub-expressões). Isso está fazendo assim:

```
x + " "
```

cujo resultado é

```
"0 "
```

Daí ele pega este resultado como operador da esquerda e faz nova "soma" com o operando da direita:

```
"0 " + y
```

cujo resultado é

```
"0 1"
```

Então ele pega este resultado e finalmente faz a última soma:

```
"0 1" + z
```

cujo resultado é

```
"0 12"
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/StringPromotion.java).

A associatividade é sempre da esquerda para a direita neste operador (existem operadores que é invertido)

Em todas as somas está usando uma *string* com um número.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui entender o motivo

Answer (score 7):

Isso ocorre por que tem uma `string` no meio, quando tem `string` ele entende que esta concatenando, tente fazer a operação antes de concatenar, para isso coloque a operação entre parenteses:

```
public class Teste {      
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 2;
    System.out.print(x + " " + (y + z));
  }      
}
```

Dessa forma o interpretador vai resolver primeiro o que esta entre parenteses e depois fazer o que esta fora, que no caso é concatenar.

Comment: Qual a razão do -1?

Comment: obrigado, deu para entender

Comment: @ramaral, tenho a impressão que tem alguém negativando sem dó o pessoal e sem explicar o motivo. Percebo isto em várias perguntas e respostas.

Comment: @ramaral e `Dherik` acredito que seja por que o `Maniero` respondeu, ai tem muita gente que vai pela pontuação, ou seja, o que ele postou esta certo e o que os outros postaram esta errado.

Comment: Em certo sentido a sua resposta até está "mais completa", já que indica como fazer o que o AP esperava: o resultado ser `0 3`.